# Hosting Windows Forms UserControl into Silverlight application

Tags: wpf, winforms, silverlight, interop, winforms-interop

I've a DLL written in Windows Forms. I need to host one UserControl from this DLL to my silverlight project. Is this possible?

In WPF, this is possible using [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) :

```
<WindowsFormsHost Name="m_WindowsFormsHost" Height="800" Width="900" >
            <winform:PlayerWindowControl />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

I want to do this in silverlight.

Comment: Hi,@Nawaz have you ever try Samvel Siradeghyan's approach below?What do you think about using  `WCF Service`?

Comment: @zionpi: No. and I'm not working on it anymore. As for WCF Service, I think it is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no similar support, nor does it seem likely any would be added, as Silverlight tries to be cross-platform.  If you want this feature, then you should also have no problems being tied to Windows by using WPF, right?

Answer (score 3):

You can't use DLLs, not written for Silverlight.
Take a look to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2354660/can-i-add-dll-to-silverlight-3-application) post.