# How to deploy win32 dll in a website so it can be used in a activex object?

Tags: c#, c++, iis, web, activex

How to deploy win32 dll in a website so it can be used in an activex object?

This problem comes from here :

[Deploying XBAP with win32 DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758568/deploying-xbap-with-win32-dll)

Comment: @Alf P.Steinbach: Any alternative? the actual engine is written in C++, so I've to use the DLL.

Comment: Outside Microsoft, ActiveX is considered one of the clearest signs that Microsoft didn't understand software engineering or security. It's horribly complex. Microsoft has a continuing battle to make normal code work and malware not, since they can't tell the two apart. The better solution is to keep your C++ on the server, and use HTML+CSS+JS to deliver only the UI to the webbrowser. You can use ASP.NET to run the C++ DLLs on a (Microsoft) webserver.

Comment: @MSalters: In fact, I'm not sure if my application uses ActiveX. I'm doing web thingy for the first time, and I've no idea about it. My actual problem is this : stackoverflow.com/questions/4758568/… ....

Answer (score 1):

What you may actually want to do is create a Browser Plugin (which is essentially an ActiveX control in IE).  There are definite downsides to using an ActiveX control, but the extreme panic implied by some of the comments is not completely justified.  I wouldn't try to do it all yourself, however; take a look at the [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org) project, which makes it fairly straightforward to write a browser plugin (in C++) that can be used in all browsers on windows.

Comment: How much time will take to create such browser plugin, with what team size? Any idea? Also, can't I make use of ActiveX itself?

Comment: Also tell me FireBreath, can I use it? in what ways?

Comment: FireBreath basically allows you to create a plugin that will work both as an ActiveX control and as a NPAPI plugin (for firefox, chrome, safari, opera).  You could use activex without FireBreath but it will take you a lot more time.  As to how long it would take -- depends on what exactly you need. Drop into the IRC room (Live Chat link at firebreath.org) sometime and chat with me. I'm usually there daylight hours MST (GMT-0700)