# In C#, Is it possible to take a forms object and use in XAML for Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hosting Windows Forms UserControl into Silverlight application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526172/hosting-windows-forms-usercontrol-into-silverlight-application)

In C#, Is it possible to take a forms object and use in XAML for Silverlight?
I found this:

Hosting a Windows Forms Control in WPF
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751761.aspx

So if it can work with WPF, can it also work for Silverlight?

Comment: similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526172/hosting-windows-forms-usercontrol-into-silverlight-application

Answer (score 1):

No, Windows Forms control can not be used within Silverlight. Silverlight is very different than WPF even though they are both based on XAML.